# How to make a custom properties dialog for a custom text background

Tags: arcobjects, java, add-in

I'm developing a custom text background in ArcObjects like in [this example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#/Circle_callout/0001000004sv000000/).

I would like to know if it is possible to make a custom properties dialog to set up parameters of this text background.

It would be another "Type" instead of "Line Callout" in the properties window:

[image: line callout parameters dialog]

The custom properties dialog would be packaged in the same .esriaddin than my custom text background.
Does the ArcObjects java API allows this ?
Does anyone know globally how to do this ?
Thanks.

I saw this example: [Sample: Simple dispersal renderer][3]. It's possible to make a custom property page for renderers and layers extending BaseCustomRendererPropertyPage and BaseCustomLayerPropertyPage. But which class could be extended to make a property page for a TextSymbol and a TextBackground ?